# Why does a virtual function break my casting?

Tags: c++, casting, virtual, downcast

I'm struggling with extending the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

class XmlTree {};

class Base
{
protected:
    int var;
public:
    Base(int var) : var(var) {}
    virtual ~Base() {}
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    void SerializeTo(XmlTree& tree) const { std::cout << var << std::endl; }
    void DeserializeFrom(const XmlTree& tree) { var = 2; }
};

void operator<<(XmlTree& tree, const Base& b) { static_cast<const Derived&>(b).SerializeTo(tree); }
void operator>>(const XmlTree& tree, Base& b) { static_cast<Derived&>(b).DeserializeFrom(tree); }

int main() {
    Base b(1);
    XmlTree tree;
    tree << b;
    tree >> b;
    tree << b;
}
```

This code works fine and prints '1' then '2' as expected.

But now I would like to implement an interface like so:

```
class XmlInterface
{
public:
    virtual void SerializeTo(XmlTree& tree) const = 0;
    virtual void DeserializeFrom(const XmlTree& tree) = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base, public XmlInterface
{
public:
    virtual void SerializeTo(XmlTree& tree) const override { std::cout << var << std::endl; }
    virtual void DeserializeFrom(const XmlTree& tree) override { var = 2; }
};
```

**TL;DR:** How can I make it work?

I have tried to use dynamic_cast and virtual destructors to make the classes polymorphic. I also tried to implement an explict downcast constructor from Base to Derived, but I failed miserably.

PS: Altering 'Base' is not an option.

Comment: `b` is not a `Derived` object, so casting it to `Derived` is **undefined behavior**.

Comment: Adding `virtual` helpfully made an existing problem obvious. It isn't the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`b` is not a `Derived` object, so casting it to `Derived` is **undefined behavior**.

In the first example, the correct solution is to move the serialize methods into `Base` and make them virtual/abstract so `Derived` can override them.  Then create a `Derived` object and remove the casts from your operators:

```
#include <iostream>

class XmlTree {};

class Base
{
protected:
    int var;
public:
    Base(int var) : var(var) {}
    virtual ~Base() {}
    virtual void SerializeTo(XmlTree& tree) const = 0;
    virtual void DeserializeFrom(const XmlTree& tree) = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived(int var) : Base(var) {}
    void SerializeTo(XmlTree& tree) const override { std::cout << var << std::endl; }
    void DeserializeFrom(const XmlTree& tree) override { var = 2; }
};

void operator<<(XmlTree& tree, const Base& b) { b.SerializeTo(tree); }
void operator>>(const XmlTree& tree, Base& b) { b.DeserializeFrom(tree); }

int main() {
    Derived d(1);
    XmlTree tree;
    tree << d;
    tree >> d;
    tree << d;
}
```

Do something similar in the second example:

```
#include <iostream>

class XmlTree {};

class Base
{
protected:
    int var;
public:
    Base(int var) : var(var) {}
    virtual ~Base() {}
};

class XmlInterface
{
public:
    virtual void SerializeTo(XmlTree& tree) const = 0;
    virtual void DeserializeFrom(const XmlTree& tree) = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base, public XmlInterface
{
public:
    Derived(int var) : Base(var) {}
    void SerializeTo(XmlTree& tree) const override { std::cout << var << std::endl; }
    void DeserializeFrom(const XmlTree& tree) override { var = 2; }
};

void operator<<(XmlTree& tree, const XmlInterface& intf) { intf.SerializeTo(tree); }
void operator>>(const XmlTree& tree, XmlInterface& intf) { intf.DeserializeFrom(tree); }

int main() {
    Derived d(1);
    XmlTree tree;
    tree << d;
    tree >> d;
    tree << d;
}
```

Comment: Sadly altering 'Base' is not an option.

Comment: @PanicSheep: then you are out of luck, unless you go the `XmlInterface` route. The code you originally showed will not work, you need to correct the design as described.

Answer (score 1):

When defining `b` as being of type `Base` and calling operator `<<`, where the operand is casted to `Derived&`, you yield undefined behaviour because `b` is not of type `Derived`. Undefined behaviour means that everything can happen, including the program working as intended. Changing the setting a little bit can yield a different "undefined behaviour", and that's what you can observe.